# actualizar fecha android por adb

Tags: android, date, adb

Necesito actualizar la fecha y hora de mi tableta por medio de `adb`, en una nexus con android 5 lo hago con:

```
adb shell date YYYYMMdd:HHMMSS
```

Sin embargo en otra tableta con android 6.0 no me permite, aparece el siguiente mensaje:

> date: cannot set date: Operation not permitted.

¿Saben a qué se puede deber ese mensaje?

Comment: La nexus la tienes rooteada?

Comment: no, la nexus no esta rooteada, lo unico que se me ocurre es que se hayan limitado los comandos adb shell en Android marshmallow